# Error en Xamarin: fakeLogOpen failed

Tags: xamarin

Estoy iniciándome con Xamarin, pero preparar el entorno se me está convirtiendo en un infierno. Nunca compila bien, siempre hay algún error que solventar, y no sobre mi código, sino sobre parámetros del proyecto o del entorno.

Al final he optado por una solución muy sencilla: He eliminado de mi PC el Visual Studio por completo y lo he instalado desde cero, marcando en la instalación que se instale Xamarin Forms.

Cuando creo un nuevo proyecto, se crea un ContentPage inicial que tiene la frase "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!". En teoría, nada más crear el proyecto, debería poder compilar y ver esta frase en el emulador de Android.

Sin embargo, lo único que obtengo es el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado sobre este error pero parece que aún nadie ha publicado una respuesta. ¿Alguien sabe de qué se trata y como solucionarlo?

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener instaladas estas dos opciones a mayores de Xamarin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las tengo instaladas. Creo que el problema se ha resuelto con una actualización que hubo hace pocos días.